# Casser les pieds à/de quelqu'un

Tags: expressions

Laquelle de ces expressions est correcte :

- Casser les pieds de quelqu'un.
- Casser les pieds à quelqu'un.

Comment: Bah, de toutes façons plus personne (de moins de 70 ans) n'utilise cette expression... c'est une autre partie du corps (échappant malheureusement à la parité !) qui s'est désormais substituée aux pauvres pieds. Registre de langage un peu plus grossier (et non plus vulgaire), mais à d'autres temps autres moeurs...

Comment: Cette expression est encore couramment utilisée.

Comment: Cette expression n'est pas utilisée en français québécois.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- "Casser les pieds de quelqu'un" = physiquement, réellement, briser les pieds d'une personne.
- "Casser les pieds à quelqu'un" = c'est une expression qui signifie ennuyer une personne, la déranger, lui causer des problèmes, l'énerver.

Answer (score 3):

"casser les pieds à quelqu'un" signifie l'ennuyer beaucoup;l`importuner. Le verbe "casser" est à prendre dans le sens d'"écraser".
 même chose pour Casser les pieds de quelqu'un : ennuyer, importuner quelqu'un

Cela dépend de ce que tu veux dire

Casser les pieds de quelqu'un. 
(c'est les pieds de quelqu'un que tu as cassé, lui appartenant)

Casser les pieds à quelqu'un. 
(tu as cassé les pieds à quelqu'un, mais ce n'est pas forcement ses pieds)

Il y a donc une différence

Answer (score 2):

La deuxième il me semble si vous entendez par cela, l'importuner, le déranger: "casser les pieds de quelqu'un", on pourrait plutôt l'utiliser lors d'un match de foot..

Answer (score 2):

"Casser les pieds", dans le contexte de l'expression, se trouve avec `de` et `à` :

Les inrockuptibles (dont il reste à prouver qu'ils massacrent la langue française) ont employé ici `de` : 
http://books.google.fr/books?id=IpcnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22casser+les+pieds+de%22&dq=%22casser+les+pieds+de%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=lGQ4U_-nGeuW0QXb4YGgCA&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBjgU

Bernard Debré emploie ici `à` : 
http://books.google.fr/books?id=qu0WB_vb2NsC&pg=PT146&dq=%22casser+les+pieds+%C3%A0%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=EWU4U_O8Hcj00gX31YG4DQ&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCDge#v=onepage&q=%22casser%20les%20pieds%20%C3%A0%22&f=false

Grammaticalement, il y a une nuance. En employant `de`, on s'intéresse plus aux pieds (donc effectivement, on *risque* plus de faire croire qu'on lui a *littéralement* cassé les pieds).

Réponse courte : employez `à` mais `de` n'est certainement pas fautif pour autant.